# Is there a way to make Trudy and Patrick non hostile after accidental friendly fire?

Tags: fallout-4

I agreed to help Trudy at the Drumlin diner with killing some raiders. In the process, I accidentally shot Patrick while we were fighting the raiders. Both characters are now hostile. I tried to leave that place for a while and continue with another story line, but even after many days they still remember my mistake.

Is there some kind of cheat to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait far enough to trigger a cell reset.

This takes, at most, 20 in-game days, and you CANNOT visit anywhere near that area at all (no checking every day; it resets the timer).

The most reliable way to trigger this is to sleep for 20 days at a far away settlement.

[Source](https://www.carls-fallout-4-guide.com/loot-resets.php)

Comment: I do not know if OP is playing on survival difficulty. But that could take 35 days to reset. [Source 1](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Survival_mode) and [Source 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/6e7wnm/how_long_do_exteriorinterior_cells_take_to/).

Comment: Will settlements get attacked if I sleep for 20 days?